# Flutter confusing behavior in user/logIn/logOut Screen

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, provider

Lately I've been struggling with this. I don´t understand flutter behavior here.

I am trying to do a user/login/register page. For that I'm using Firebase cloud firestore and FireBase Auth. I have a provider to that stores the status of the user

```
enum Status { Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated, Register, AuthenticatingRegister, RegisterTransit, RegisterNS, AuthenticatingRegisterNS }

class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  FirebaseUser _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;
```

That's the way I implement my SignIn Function. SingUp, LogIn LogOut are very similar.

```
  Future<bool> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password, );
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The I have my User Screen when, depending on the State, I choose which screen to show.

```
class UserScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          switch (user.status) {
            case Status.RegisterNS:
            case Status.AuthenticatingRegisterNS:
              return FormNS();
            case Status.RegisterTransit:
              return LoginMeio();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return LoginPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return UserInfoPage(user: user.user);
            case Status.Register:
            case Status.AuthenticatingRegister:
              return RegisterScreen();
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
            default:
              return Splash();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am unsig Bottom Tab Navigator to navigate trough the app.

Everything is working as intended, a part of a little thing. 
I am initializing the Status as Uninitialized on the `UserRepository` Provider. Every time I open the `UserScreen`, for a brief amount of time, before I am redirected to the correct screen, the splash screen is showed. That is perfect for the first time the user wants to navigate to the `UserScreen`. But After that I just want the correct page to open directly without passing trough the Splash Screen.

If I'm not being enough clear pleas tell me.

My question is. If I go to a page and comeback to the User Screen, how can I prevent the Status to be initialized as Status.Uninitialized before it recognizes the correct Status and return the correct page?

Answer (score 0):

To sign in the user, you call this:

```
await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password, );
```

As the use of `await` already shows, this operation is asynchronous: Firebase needs to call its authentication servers here, to check the email and password combination, and this takes some time.

The amount of time this call takes depends on many factors. While it may be quite fast for you, it could take multiple seconds for some of your users that are in more remote locations, or otherwise on slower internet connections.

But indeed, showing a splash screen very briefly is also not a great user experience, so you have a few options that I can think of:

1. First off, I'd consider if you really need to sign in the user each time. Firebase Authentication automatically persists the user authentication state, and restores that state when they restart the app. So instead of calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword` each time, consider using `await _auth.currentUser()`.

   Unfortunately this is also an asynchronous operation, since Firebase needs to check whether the ID token of the user is still valid (and refresh is otherwise). But it may take less time than the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.
2. You could keep a local flag (for example in [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)) that flags that the user was signed in before, and use that to skip the splash screen. Note that the user's sign in might have expired or fail, so your optimistic assumption (based on the local flag) might be wrong, in which case you might still want to show the splash screen.
3. You could delay showing the splash screen for a short moment, to prevent most of the flashing. Say that you notice that on average the re-authenticating takes less than 0.5 seconds. You could change your code to only show the splash screen after 0.5 seconds, ensuring that users don't see if unless it takes longer than 0.5 seconds.

   How effective this is, and what exact cut-off point to use, depends on the distribution of the times it takes to sign in for all your users. So you may want to start tracking across your users how long the sign in takes with something like Firebase Analytics, or Performance Monitoring.